# Sum even and odd number output not correct

Tags: python

> **INPUTS 1**
>
> "1 2 3 4 5 6"   <<< YES WITH SPACE
>
> > **Results returned**
> >
> > - The summation of even and odd numbers are 12 and 6 **[x]**
> > - The difference between biggest and smallest number is 5    **[✓]**
> > - The count of even numbers and odd numbers are 6 6 **[x]**
>
> **INPUT 2**
>
> 1 2 3 4
>
> > **Results returned**
> >
> > - The summation of even and odd numbers are 6 and 4 **[✓]**
> > - The difference between biggest and smallest number is 3 **[✓]**
> > - The count of even numbers and odd numbers are 4 4 **[X]**

what is wrong with my code? can someone enlighten me???

```
even_sum, odd_sum = 0,0


    s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
    numbers = map(int, s.split())

    for num in numbers:
        if num%2 ==0:
                    evencount = len(numbers)
                    even_sum += num

    else:
                    oddcount = len(numbers)
                    odd_sum += num



    max = max(numbers)
    min = min(numbers)
    difference = max - min

    print numbers
    print "The summation of even and odd numbers are " + str(even_sum) + " and " + str(odd_sum)
    print "The difference between biggest and smallest number is " + str(difference)
    print "The count of even numbers and odd numbers are " + str(evencount) + " " + str(oddcount)
```

Comment: What did you get from your debugger?

Comment: What do you mean? The result returned is as above

Comment: you set the length `evencount = len(numbers)` when not all the numbers are even

Answer (score 4):

Your `else` is aligned directly under the `for` which can also take an `else`, so the sum of even numbers is taken correctly while the sum of odd numbers is the last value of `num` in the for loop. You should move your `else` block to align with the `if`.

Comment: What is the right way to approach this? I am getting myopic after hours of solving this

Comment: Make the indentation of the `else` block align with the `if`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in these lines

```
evencount = len(numbers)
oddcount = len(numbers)
```

In both cases, you end up saying

```
evencount = all numbers i've encountered 
oddcount = all numbers i've encountered
```

that is why you get `4,4` for evencount and oddcount, since you have 4 numbers as input.

change it to

```
evencount = 0
oddcount = 0
for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 ==0:
        evencount += 1
        even_sum += num

    else:
        oddcount += 1
        odd_sum += num
```

Answer (score 1):

dont have enough rep to comment, but I think the answer is probalby that your else statement is not properly indented...

Also I think the logic on your even and odd count is off, I think it should be something more like:

`evencount = evencount+1`

Try this:

```
even_sum, odd_sum = 0,0
evencount, oddcount = 0,0

s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())

for num in numbers:
    if num%2 ==0:
                evencount = evencount +1# len(numbers)
                even_sum += num

    else:
                oddcount = oddcount+1#len(numbers)
                odd_sum += num



max = max(numbers)
min = min(numbers)
difference = max - min

print numbers
print "The summation of even and odd numbers are " + str(even_sum) + " and " + str(odd_sum)
print "The difference between biggest and smallest number is " + str(difference)
print "The count of even numbers and odd numbers are " + str(evencount) + " " + str(oddcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've received corrections to your code from other answers (namely `evencount += 1`), but just for some potential further investigations into the capabilities of the language here's another approach to the solution.

Python has a strong iterator algebra and in the itertools recipes is `partition` which splits a list into parts based on the condition, in fact the example given is splitting odd from even: [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

So using this would look like:

```
import itertools as it
s = "1 2 3 4 5 6"
numbers = list(map(int, s.split()))  # Need `list` in Py3 okay to skip in Py2

# See itertools recipes
def partition(pred, iterable):
    t1, t2 = it.tee(iterable)
    return it.filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

is_odd = lambda x: x%2
even, odd = map(list, partition(is_odd, numbers))

print("The summation of even and odd numbers are {} and {}".format(sum(even), sum(odd)))
print("The difference between biggest and smallest number is {}".format(max(numbers)-min(numbers)))
print("The count of even numbers and odd numbers are {} {}".format(len(even), len(odd)))
```

Result:

```
The summation of even and odd numbers are 12 and 9
The difference between biggest and smallest number is 5
The count of even numbers and odd numbers are 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with following statements :

- evencount = len(numbers)
- oddcount = len(numbers)
- else indentation

Solution is ::

```
even_sum, odd_sum = 0,0
even_count,odd_count = 0,0

s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())

for num in numbers:

    if num%2 == 0:
        even_sum = even_sum + num
        even_count = even_count + 1
    else:
        odd_sum = odd_sum + num
        odd_count = odd_count + 1

mx = max(numbers)
mn = min(numbers)
difference = mx - mn

print 'The summation of even %d and odd numbers are %d ' % (even_sum,odd_sum)
print "The difference between biggest and smallest number is " + str(difference)
print "The count of even numbers and odd numbers are " + str(even_count) + " " + str(odd_count)
```